# Addressable RGB lights on a battery

Tags: batteries, rgb, controller, addressing

I'm working on a DIY project making an RGB tube light or wand. My concern is how I can run an addressable RGB strip on batteries.

Things I have;

1. A one metre strip with 144 pixels on it that needs 5V and 8640mA or 8.64A (60*144) at max.
2. Magic home controller that has maximum power 5V, less than 30W. I assume it is 5V, 6A.

I want to run this strip for 4hours or more. I also want to charge the batteries with a module (e.g. TP4056)  along with batteries that can fit in the handle of the tube light. The handle of the tube would be simply a 1" inch (diameter) PVC pipe.

I'm a photographer and don't have complex knowledge of electronics. What is the easiest method to make it happen?

Comment: THe controller itself probably uses negligible power, so you need enough battery for the lights.  You probably also don't want to run the lights with the R, G and B channels all at the same time, so your current will be lower (probably more like 20-30mA).

Comment: You can get away with a lot less battery if you figure out how much current your strip *actually* uses at a reasonable brightness. These strips are usually specified for more current than you actually use. e.g. if you are doing full brightness red, green or blue, that is only 1/3 of the current

Comment: Usually for a 5V project I'd say the easiest way is to cannibalize a USB power bank, but I don't know if they make ones with the battery capacity you need.

Comment: This is close, but doesn't meet your built-in recharge requirement. I made a clear tube with addressable LED strips. I cut the strip so it is a little less than 144 LEDs, maybe 120. It uses 4 AA NiMH batteries. With all LEDs on bright, the voltage is pulled down enough so it locks up. But, at reasonable brightness it works fine. As for battery life, AAs are 2000 mAh. So, to run for 4 hours you need to be at 500 mA.